# SQLMetal fails to create DBML from SQL Server 2005 database

Tags: c#, sql-server, model-view-controller, stored-procedures, sqlmetal

As the title already says, am I trying to create an dbml-file by using **SQLMetal**. The background for this action is to create a **C#-Codefile** which contains all tables, function, views, stored procedures and so on for using it in an **MVC-Application**.

Now to the problem. When i am starting SQLMetal from command it takes so time, shows some minor warnings and breaks in an Error (DBML1057).
As I read the error-message, SQLMetal is trying to extract a stored procedure, that is not existing. I looked at the database a dozen times but could definetly not find such a procedure. Maybe this procedure was called so long before.
i.e. you create a SP named "**GetGameDatesDesc**" and later you rename it to "**GetGameDates**". SQLMetal (in my case) is looking for "**GetGameDateDesc**" I think. But where has SQLMetal this information from? I can't find a word in database. I looked over all views, functions,... bot no avail. This function isn't part of the database anymore.

Edit -------------- 02/14/2011 --------------

Here are the warnings from SQLMetal:

Error DBML1042: The member attribute '**CCode**' in the Column element of the Type element '**GetGameDatesDesc**' has been used already.
Error DBML1057: The storage attribute or its default value '**_CCode**' in the Column element of the Type '**GetGameDatesDesc**' has been used already.

Comment: I don't know the cause - but maybe just create a dummy sproc just to make it happy?

Comment: For other sprocs it works as it should. So it's not a problem with sprocs at all. I can't figure out where SQLMetal gets the information about a sproc that isn't existing anymore.
So if i can find the place where "**GetGameDatesDesc**" is written down i could delete this entry and SQLMetal will not throw an error...

Answer (score 0):

It looks that there is some error in one of your existing stored procedures. Maybe you delete or rename some stored procedure, but some another stored procedure still have a call of that deleted or renamed.
Try to generate SQL script that creates all the stored procedures using SQL Management Studio
(Right mouse click on database -> Tasks -> Generate Scripts) and search in generated script stored procedure name that causes error.

Comment: I already tried this, but the name of the sproc which throws the error can't be found there.

Answer (score 0):

This is a unfortunate limitation of SqlMetal. As the SQL Server information_schema has a limit of 4000 characters on the SP code, SqlMetal is using the `sys.sql_modules` view to look for SPs. But that view isn't updated by the `sp_rename` function, so if you rename a SP, SqlMetal will not work correctly. The recommendation found in [sp_rename documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx) is to drop and recreate these kind of objects:

> Renaming a stored procedure, function,
>   view, or trigger will not change the
>   name of the corresponding object name
>   in the definition column of the
>   sys.sql_modules catalog view.
>   Therefore, we recommend that sp_rename
>   not be used to rename these object
>   types. Instead, drop and re-create the
>   object with its new name.

The solution would be to drop that SP and recreate it as SQL Server will use the object_id to delete the corresponding `sys.sql_modules` row.

Comment: Am i right, that SQL Server will delete also all dependend entries in `sys.sql_modules`, or will i have to do this myself?

Comment: Yes, it uses the object_id to delete the corresponding sys.sql_modules row.

Comment: Kay. Thanks. I could try this tomorrow. So, if there are another errors, i will report. And, if this solves the problem, i will post it here anyway ;)

Comment: I looked at this view but there is no entry for the old sproc. Any other ideas where SQLMetal is getting the information about the non-existing sproc?